# In SSRS, setting font color of text box using IIF does not work

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder

I have tried nearly everything I can think of to get this to work, to no avail. I have a text box that I want the font color to be light gray if a certain value is true and black if it is false. Here are all the expressions that I've tried:

```
=IIF(Fields!is_hold.Value,"LightGrey","Black")
=IIF(Fields!is_hold.Value,"#d2d2d2","#000000")
=If(Fields!is_hold.Value,"LightGrey","Black")
=If(Fields!is_hold.Value,"#d2d2d2","#000000")
=IIF(True,"#d2d2d2","#000000")
=IIF(True,"LightGrey","Black")
=If(True,"LightGrey","Black")
=If(True,"#d2d2d2","#000000")
=SWITCH(True,"#d2d2d2",False,"#000000")
=SWITCH(True,"LightGrey",False,"Black")
```

The strange part is that it works fine on another subreport when I pass [is_hold] as a parameter:

```
=If(Parameters!IsHold.Value, "#d2d2d2", "#000000")
```

I have tried it in both Chrome and IE.

UPDATE: This only fails on text boxes. If I set the color of a line using the same expression, it works fine.

UPDATE 2: The problem exists on the server side. Previewing the form in Report Builder, the text colors exactly as it should. I checked the CSS classes that are auto-generated for the elements, and there is no color attribute when I use the expression. If I set the color directly, the color attribute exists in the CSS. Restarting SSRS service did not help.

Comment: you are missing the `=`

Comment: No, the value is a boolean. Also, see the example where I just used True. That should work regardless of the variable value.

Comment: i don't think so.... try equating it

Comment: See my update. The expression works on other elements, just not the text box.

Comment: Also, I have tried equating it. I've tried "= True", "= 1", "="true"", etc.

Comment: `=TRUE`   no double quotes

Comment: As I said, I've tried all those things. Also, the expression works fine. I tested it on other elements. It's not the "equating it". Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: what's the actual value of the parameter? can you make it 0 and 1?

Comment: I appreciate you helping, but I don't think you're getting what I'm saying. I have two elements: a line and a text box. I use the same expression for setting the color of both. The line changes color, but the text box does not. There is _nothing_ wrong with the expression.

Comment: where did you set the condition? should be at the border shading though for all borders

Comment: Could have to do with setting to display html or something similar

Answer (score 0):

Well, don't know what you are missing as I tried all possible scenarios (table, line, box, and textbox) with the following expression as the color expression and it all works fine for me.

```
=iif(Parameters!Bool.Value,"Red","Blue")
```

And the result is...

**In dev:**

[image]

**And in deployed version:**

[image]

Can you point at What I am missing so that I can try that bit too??

P.S.: Sorry as this not an answer but not able to comment in that much details.

Comment: I asked a question on MSDN. Pretty sure this is a server-side issue, as it looks fine in Report Builder. I'm using SSRS 2016. Thanks for checking, though. If I get an update, I'll post it here.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d173fe92-71d5-4c4b-a86c-3a96d18848cf/ssrs-2016-server-does-not-correctly-style-text-boxes-when-using-an-expression?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Sweet. Good luck mate.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly old thread, but I came across it while researching a similar issue.  For me, everything rendered correctly in Report Builder but dynamic color expressions failed when viewed through the browser.  This was supposedly fixed by [KB4338240](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/kb4338240-fix-toggle-item-font-color-and-background-color-expressions-do-not-work-correctly-together-in-ssrs-402b51ae-b28a-6f13-6c0e-b907fd29b7ba) (SQL SP2 CU2) which fixed a bug related to color, toggle item usage in combo with the Can Grow attribute.  This KB should have been what I needed, except I am running SQL 2016 SP3, presumably already containing the bug fix, and still experienced the issue.  Taking some direction from another search thread, I was able to resolve by selecting the Textbox properties and changing the the Markup type from None, to HTML. I did not include any html markup code for the color or style, just the setting change resolved the expression based color issue.